# Get exit status of a process in bash

Tags: c++, bash, exit-code

I have a C++ executable named `Test`. I want to find out the `GetExitCodeProcess()` code when the execution is completed.

I can find out the status code by writing the following in another wrapper program as such:

```cpp
...
int status = system("./Test");
```

and then check for WIFSIGNALED / WIFSTOPPED etc statuses.

However, instead of writing a wrapper program, can I get the exit status code from the PID of the `.Test` program by writing a *bash* script?

**Edit:** Does writing a `$` in the *bash* after executing `./Test` give the solution to the above problem?

**Edit:** Summary is -- when I run an executable from the command line, how do I (not a program) get the exit status?

Comment: You are using c++ to call script, use c++ to get the exit status-- don't call another script, there's too many things going on that way.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can simply do a `echo $?` after executing the command/bash which will output the exit code of the program.

Every command returns an exit status (sometimes referred to as a return
status or exit code). A successful command returns a `0`, while an
unsuccessful one returns a non-zero value that usually can be interpreted
as an error code. Well-behaved `UNIX` commands, programs, and utilities return
a `0` exit code upon successful completion, though there are some exceptions.

```sh
# Non-zero exit status returned -- command failed to execute.
echo $?    
  
echo

# Will return 113 to shell.
# To verify this, type "echo $?" after script terminates.    
exit 113             

# By convention, an 'exit 0' indicates success,
# while a non-zero exit value means an error or anomalous condition
```

Alternately if you wish to identify return code for a background process/script (started with `nohup` or run in background `&` operator) you could get the pid of the process/script started and wait for it to terminate and then get the exit code.

```sh
# Some random number for the process-id is returned
./foo.sh &
[1] 28992          

# Get process id of the background process
echo $!          
28992 

# Waits until the process determined by the number is complete
wait 28992       

[1]+  Done         ./foo.sh

# Prints the return code of the process
echo $?          
0
```

Also take a look at [Bash Hackers Wiki - Exit Status](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/dict/terms/exit_status#exit_status)

Comment: I don't think it does, b/c system() is already giving him the same information $? does.  While this answer has received upvotes, it applies to a bash script calling another script, not a c++ program calling a bash script.  From my understanding of the OP.

Comment: If i remember right, from the OP 'However instead of writing a wrapper program, can i get the exit status code from the pid of the .Test program by writing a bash script?' which is basically bash script calling another script. Am OK to delete the post if found irrelevant which in this case is not.

Answer (score 8):

You are approaching this wrong-- system() already returns the exist status: zero for success, non-zero for failure.  What is likely happening is your "Test" script is written incorrectly or you are testing "status" incorrectly.  I've seen the following scripting mistakes from developers.

```
run_some_java
echo "Done"
```

At no time are they tracking the exit code, the script returns the last exit code-- of the echo command.  Which makes it always successful.  Here are two ways of exiting correctly (and I know other coders thing some more advanced ways are better than this first one, but I don't think that's what this thread is about).  Crawl, then walk, then run.

If you need the exit status, but want all the shell commands to execute.

```
return_code=0

mv $letters $ARCHIVE
return_code=$(($return_code + $?))

mv $letters $ARCHIVE
return_code=$(($return_code + $?))

exit $return_code
```

If you want to exit on the failure, there is `set -e` to look into, and here is another way.

```
mv $letters $ARCHIVE || exit 1
mv $letters $ARCHIVE || exit 2
```