# How to store the values from a script in a variable in linux

Tags: linux, bash, variables

I want to pass the PASSED or FAILED value from a script. If the script is successfully triggered, then I want to pass the PASSED value. And if it is not successfully triggered, then I want to pass the FAILED value. And these PASSED or FAILED values needs to be stored in a variable in another script.

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: The standard, canonical way of signaling success vs failure is via the script's [exit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36837149/get-exit-status-of-a-process-in-bash)

Comment: If I run a script successfully, then I want to get the PASSED value to be passed and get stored in a variable inside a script.

Comment: This might help: [How do I set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4651437/3776858)

Comment: How can we get the automated values like PASSED if the  script runs successfully and FAILED if the script didn't runs successfully?

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.