# powershell return value $? and custom exit code

Tags: bash, powershell, return-value

I installed powershell on Linux-Box.
At end of my *.PS1 file I put the following code:

```
Exit 2222
```

I run my ps1 file such as:

```
pwsh-lts -File my.ps1
```

But I can't access to 2222. How can I access it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get exit status of a process in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36837149/get-exit-status-of-a-process-in-bash)

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:bash]? Exit codes on Unix-like platforms are a single byte, so in the range 0-255. In the environments I have access to, 2222 gets truncated to 174, but Powershell might do something entirely different.

Comment: Unfortunately, `$?` can't do it.

Comment: It's probably tagged bash because the user is using the bash shell. I think the finer details of its single byte nature was clearly unknown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash reflects the last exist code via the `$?` variable.

Let's give it a try (I'm using bash on Ubuntu on WSL2, but you'll find the same behavior in bash on any little-endian platform):

```
mathias@laptop:~/test$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
mathias@laptop:~/test$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
mathias@laptop:~/test$ echo $?
0
mathias@laptop:~/test$ pwsh -Command 'exit 2222'
mathias@laptop:~/test$ echo $?
174
```

So `$?` returns a value of `174`, rather than 2222 - which is exactly what you should expect!

As [triplee notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72140483/powershell-return-value-and-custom-exit-code#comment127463930_72140483), the size of the underlying value is an unsigned byte, meaning its value will be truncated to 8 bits, giving you the value `174`. This can be observed if you convert both values to a binary string:

```
mathias@laptop:~/test$ pwsh -Command '2222,174 |% {[convert]::ToString($_, 2).PadLeft(16, "0")}'
0000100010101110
0000000010101110
#       ^^^^^^^^
# Notice how the least significant 8 bits are the same
```

So there's you're answer:

- To read the last exit code in bash: evaluate `$?`
- To avoid having the value truncated: pick an exit code < 255 (so it fits in an unsigned byte)