# How to capture exit code of a perl script which is called from a shell script

Tags: shell, csh, exit-code

I have this sample perl code, where $a $b $c values can be changed and has exit code $ex. I call this from another shell script, which is affected by abc.pl's  exit code. How do I capture just the exit code of this perl.

```
my $a=0; my $b=0; my $c=0;
my $sum = $a+$b+$c; $ex = 0;
if($sum == 0){
    print "success"; print " $ex \n";
}else{
    $ec=1 ; print "Not success"; print " $ex \n";
}
exit $ex;
```

Sample shell script.

```
echo start
set ecd = `abc.pl`
echo $ecd
echo stop
```

Here $ecd prints whatever is the output of abc.pl, but not just the exit code.

Now I have problem with if else loop,

```
set ecd = `abc.pl`
set status = $?
echo $status
if ( $status == 0 ) then
    echo "Here Status is $status"
else
    echo "Status is $status"
endif
echo $status
```

The value of status seems to change before and after the if loop, everytime it prints only the msg in if condition.
Sample output.
1
Here Status is 0
0
Please help to correct this.
Please suggest me how I can get better with the basics aswell. Help is very much appreciated.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36837149/get-exit-status-of-a-process-in-bash

Comment: Yeah, that is correct , it is csh shell.

Comment: @ikegami please suggest.

Comment: Suggest what? It's already correctly fixed, so there's nothing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$?` contains the exit code of the last executed command.

```
set ecd = `abc.pl`
set status = $?
```