# If else loop not working in csh shell script

Tags: shell, csh, exit-code

This is sample perl code. abc.pl

```
my $a=0; my $b=0; my $c=0;
my $sum = $a+$b+$c; $ex = 0;
if($sum == 0){
    print "success"; print " $ex \n";
}else{
    $ec=1 ; print "Not success"; print " $ex \n";
}
exit $ex;
```

This is my shell script

```
set ecd = `abc.pl`
set status = $?
echo $status
if ( $status == 0 ) then
    echo "Here Status is $status"
else
    echo "Status is $status"
endif
echo $status
```

Now I have problem with if else loop,
The value of status seems to change before and after the if loop, everytime it prints only the msg in if condition.
Sample output.

```
1 
Here Status is 0 
0
```

Please help to correct this. I think the status if reflecting the prev command if ?  Please suggest how can I make this if loop work correctly.
Please suggest me how I can get better with the basics aswell. Help is very much appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.
This is continuation to the question : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75523005/how-to-capture-exit-code-of-a-perl-script-which-is-called-from-a-shell-script][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not familiar with `csh` but I believe `$status` is a csh's special variable that is equivalent to `$?`.

So the `$status` in `if` statement at line 4 will be updated by the exit code of `echo $status` at line 3, as always equals to 0.

Try changing your `$status` variable with `$rc` or anything else.

I'd rather recommend you to rewrite your shell script with bsh/bash though.

Answer (score 1):

You did

```perl
$ec=1;
exit $ex;
```

instead of

```perl
$ex=1;
exit $ex;
```

ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings;`. It would have caught this error.

---

Note that `die` causes `perl` to exit with a non-zero status, so you could use the following:

```perl
use v5.14;     # This implicitly does `use strict;`
use warnings;

my $x = 0;
my $y = 0;
my $z = 0;

my $sum = $x + $y + $z;

if ( $sum != 0 ) {
   die( "Error\n" );
}

say "Success";
```

Avoid the variable names `$a` and `$b` as those are semi-special.